# Deleting specific footnote in gtsummary

Tags: r, gtsummary

How can I delete specific footnote in the gtsummary table. For example I would to delete footnote `2 Wilcoxon rank sum test; Pearson's Chi-squared test` but leave the other one.

```
library(gtsummary)
library(dplyr)

trial[c("age", "grade", "trt")] %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt, missing = "no") %>%
  add_p()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to use the `modify_footnote()` function to remove the footnotes. Example below!

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.5.0'

tbl <- 
  trial[c("age", "grade", "trt")] %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt, missing = "no") %>%
  add_p() %>%
  # remove footnotes
  modify_footnote(c(all_stat_cols(), p.value) ~ NA)
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2021-11-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>